# String List conversion to float python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a file with lines of numbers represting vectors.
I am trying to convert it into list of lists of floats.
Right now, my problem is that it takes only the first row of each line.
I have try to loop over each index, but I face an error of "can not convert string into float"

Here is my code:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
input_val_arr = list(map(float, [i.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in content]))
```

**input format:**

```
0.03518 -0.02543 ... (dim = 100)

0.0025865 -0.01867 ....

...

(dim = ALOT)
```

**desire output:**

```
[[ 0.03518 , -0.02543 ...]

 [0.0025865 -0.01867 ...]
```

...

]]

I have tried to change my code to:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
input_val_arr = []
for index in range(x_dim):
    temp_list = list(map(float, [i.split(' ', 1)[index] for i in content]))
    input_val_arr.append(temp_list)
```

And I get the following error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0.02543 0.0025865 ...'

Comment: Can you post a sample of your file and expected output?

Comment: if you don't want to do it manually because of learning about it in detail - I'd recommend using `csv` or `pandas`. Especially with the latter it's a one liner, completely adjustable to whatever column separators, decimal signs or whatever you have. And then you can break your mind about interesting things like how to interpret or visualize your data...

Comment: Add try catch and see what is the data. Then only anyone can suggest you anything.

Comment: Please post the whole error (which also contains the text that couldn't be converted, e.g.: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,3'`).

Comment: Ok, updated with input&output example and the error I get when I change the code. Thank you.

Comment: There has been an answer which seems to work (pending an edit), but i.split(' ',1) means your line is being split into two parts. Assuming you have more than two numbers per line, youre correctly converting the first number, and then attempting to float(remaining numbers on line). What happens if you remove the '1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to extract all floats from your file. and then use `map` to convert it to float object.

**Ex:**

```
import re
res = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        data = re.findall("-?\d+\.\d+", line)
        if data:
            floatData = list(map(float, data))
            res.append(floatData)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.03518, -0.02543], [0.0025865, -0.01867]]
```

Comment: Almost perfect, problem is it igonre the sign of the number

Comment: @RanEldan. Try: `data = re.findall("\-?\d+\.\d+", line)`

Comment: Updated snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple and quick approach:

```
line = "0.0025865 -0.01867"
values  = list(map(float, line.split()))
print(values)
```

Output:

```
[0.0025865, -0.01867]
```

If you want to have a list with lists, where a list represents a line from a file, then something like this will work:

```
result = []

for i in range(5):
    line = "0.0025865 -0.01867\n"
    values  = list(map(float, line.split()))
    result.append(values)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0.0025865, -0.01867], [0.0025865, -0.01867], [0.0025865, -0.01867], [0.0025865, -0.01867], [0.0025865, -0.01867]]
```

Here for simplicity, I used a single input called `line` 5 times, but in your case, the line will come from your file.

Here we assume that the line is a line from a file and that it contains numeric values. You should complete the code to handle the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your file:

```
0.03518 -0.02543 0.5469 0.538
```

The separation is the space.

```
with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

content = content = content.split(" ")
content = [eval(elt) for elt in content]

# Output: Out[43]: [0.03518, -0.02543, 0.5469, 0.538]
```

If you have several lines as shown:

```
with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    content= f.readlines()

content = [line.split(" ") for line in content]
content = [[eval(x) for x in elt] for elt in content]
```

You might need to add a `strip("\n")` if required.

Answer (score 0):

I do know, you are asking through python. But whatever you want achieve can be simply done using numpy.  and `np.loadtxt` as multiple options, which helps to process flat files which consists numerical data.

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.loadtxt('file_name.txt')
numbers
```

and output will be like below

```
[[ 3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02,
        -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,
         3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02,
        -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,
         3.518e+03, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02],
       [ 3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02,
        -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,
         3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02,
        -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02,
         3.518e+03, -2.543e-02,  3.518e-02, -2.543e-02]]
```